# Regex multiple exclusion alternatives and detection of MD5

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation

I want to exclude some specific words and if those words doesn't match, then should match an md5 hash for example.

Here a small log as example

```
"value": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "u_jira_status": "", "u_quarter_closed": "", "file_hash": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "escalation": "0", "upon_approval": "proceed", "correlation_id": "", "cyber_kill_change": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "sys_id": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", "u_business_service": "", "destination_ip": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6", u'test': u'9db92f08db4f951423c87d84f39619ef'
```

As you can see there is multiple values that should match, just excluding "value" and "id"

Here the regex I am using so far

```
([^value|^id](\":\s\"|':\su')\b)[a-fA-F\d]{32}\b
```

I know that [value|id]=(v|a|l|u|e|i|d) so this is not what I want, I want to exclude the words, not just the letters.
So I need another option to exclude those words, **I cannot use "<", "!", "=" or "*"** so something like this **(?<!value|id) is not an option for me**

There is two cases where after the exclusion could be "something": "hash" or 'something': u'hash'

Whit the previous regex the result is the following.
[image: Test example]

The result is excluding value and id as expected, but there is a value called "cyber_kill_change" that is not matching for some reason and for the other ones is matching "file_hash", "destination_ip" and 'test' as expected. Now as you can see in the previous image the matches are

h": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6
p": "ef51be4506d7d287abc8c26ea6c495f6
t': u'9db92f08db4f951423c87d84f39619ef

I'm looking for a result where the MD5 is showed, something like the following

9db92f08db4f951423c87d84f39619ef

Can someone explain to me how to match correctly, please?

Note For the exclusions I cannot use something similar to this (?<!value|id) The < and ! are not accepted by the software where I want to add the regex. If it helps I am trying to use this regex for XSOAR, here some documentation of the permitted [Syntax](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/9-1/pan-os-web-interface-help/objects/objects-custom-objects/objects-custom-objects-data-patterns/syntax-for-regular-expression-data-patterns)

Comment: Don't try to use regular expressions to process JSON. Use a JSON parser, then process the resulting data.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, The software I'm using is XSOAR, there is a module where you can extract some patterns, I can only use Regex for this, I know that is not the best option for json but is the only one that I have, this module does not permit *, actually I tried something like this \b(?:value|id)(*SKIP)(*FAIL) but is not allowed because of the * 
The flavor is Python.

Comment: The regex engine for that tool seems to support a limited set of features. Perhaps try it like this with a capture group `value": "[a-fA-F\d]{32}"|id": "[a-fA-F\d]{32}"|"([a-fA-F\d]{32})"` https://regex101.com/r/3bjpNp/1